# remove "!!omap" from yaml file generation?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

i am using this to write my file

```
    yaml1 = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml1.preserve_quotes = True

    with open('output.yaml', "wb") as fp:
        yaml1.dump(file, fp)
```

`file` in runtime prints as follows:

```
  ordereddict(
  [
    ('formatVersion', '0.11'), 
    ('deviceDescription', 'test Master-File'), 
    ('strings', [ordereddict([('name', 'label_1'), ('en', 'test'), ('es', 'test'), ('de', 'test'), ('fr', 'test'), ('it', 'test'), ('ru', 'test'), ('zh', 'test')]),
                 ordereddict([('name', 'label_2'), ('en', 'test'), ('es', 'test'), ('de', 'test'), ('fr', 'test'), ('it', 'test'), ('ru', 'test'), ('zh', 'test')])
  ])])
```

i expect this output:

```
formatVersion: "0.11"

deviceDescription: test Master-File

strings:
- name: label_1
  en: test
  es: test
  de: test
  fr: test
  it: test
  ru: test
  zh: test

- name: label_2
  en: test
  es: test
  de: test
  fr: test
  it: test
  ru: test
  zh: test
```

but i get this:

```
formatVersion: "0.11"
deviceDescription: test Master-File

strings:
- !!omap
  - name: label_1
  - en: test
  - es: test
  - de: test
  - fr: test
  - it: test
  - ru: test
  - zh: test
- !!omap
  - name: label_2
  - en: test
  - es: test
  - de: test
  - fr: test
  - it: test
  - ru: test
  - zh: test
```

How can i get rid of - !!omap ?

Comment: `!!omap` means that it's an ordered mapping, see https://yaml.org/type/omap.html. Try converting the ordered dictionaries to regular dictionaries in `file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ordereddict`, which is a dict for which the keys are kept in insertion order expliciltly.
This always differed from the normal Python `dict`, which used to be not ordered in all of Python 1 and Python 2 releases and the early 3.x releases, all out-of d-date.

YAML mappings is are unordered by defintion (although of course they are ordered in the YAML document.

So to make sure that you get an ordered dictionary back when you dump en then load an ordered dictionary to YAML (which not necessarily have to be with the same software or programming language used), the ordered-ness information has to be stored in YAML and it does that by using a tagged sequence of single item mappings.

Therefore your expectation for the output are wrong. If you want the output that you get, you should
just convert it to a normal dict recursively, and dump:

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml.compat import ordereddict
import ruamel.yaml


data = ordereddict(
  [
    ('formatVersion', '0.11'), 
    ('deviceDescription', 'test Master-File'), 
    ('strings', [ordereddict([('name', 'label_1'), ('en', 'test'), ('es', 'test'), ('de', 'test'), ('fr', 'test'), ('it', 'test'), ('ru', 'test'), ('zh', 'test')]),
                 ordereddict([('name', 'label_2'), ('en', 'test'), ('es', 'test'), ('de', 'test'), ('fr', 'test'), ('it', 'test'), ('ru', 'test'), ('zh', 'test')])
  ])])

def unorderdict(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k: unorderdict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return [unorderdict(elem) for elem in d]
    return d

dx = unorderdict(data)
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(dx, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
formatVersion: '0.11'
deviceDescription: test Master-File
strings:
- name: label_1
  en: test
  es: test
  de: test
  fr: test
  it: test
  ru: test
  zh: test
- name: label_2
  en: test
  es: test
  de: test
  fr: test
  it: test
  ru: test
  zh: test
```

Since you don't load your data from a YAML document, it makes not difference to set `preserve_quotes` that is
only upserved during loading.

If you really need the extra empty line you'll need to convert to `ruamel.yaml.CommentedMap` and muck about with the comments on those.